# How to call/invoke arrow function after await statement in async function

Tags: node.js

Hey guys I would like to know syntax to await my own constructed function.

```
async function func(){
const result = await ()=>{
return 2;
}
console.log(result);
}
```

This example results in [Function] I would like to get 2

I am not able to google it as I do not know how to name it even sorry :)

Comment: You need to create a function which returns a Promise. Then call that function in await and the result of the promise will be store in the variable.

Comment: I understand that, I do not want to create new function i want to use arrow function instead of regular function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because result is the function. You need to somehow invoke that function and assign the return of the function into `result`.

What you're looking for is:

```
async function func(){
    const result = await (()=>{
        return 2;
    })();
    console.log(result);
}
```

Or you can embrace the fact that `result` is a function and just do:

```
async function func(){
    const result = await ()=>{
        return 2;
    };
    console.log(result());
}
```

Comment: Yes, Thanks :) How would you name it so I can change title to this question ?

Comment: How to invoke arrow function after await statement ? or Could be ?

Comment: You can either self invoke it right after the definition, like my first code piece, or you can assign it to a variable and invoke the variable, like my second code piece.